# Java DB in jdk 10 not possible?

Tags: derby, java-10, javadb

I'm creating a simple Java DB in my netbeans application, but I noticed the 'Create Database' option is greyed out and when I looked at the properties, there is no Java DB folder filled in. I recently started using JDK10, and I've noticed this doesn't have a DB folder anymore, therefore I can't set the Java DB installation folder and database location. Is this something new since JDK10? I remember it used to work fine with JDK1.8

Comment: “Java DB” was an Apache Derby integrated into the JDK. If you want to use that database, you can download and install it yourself. That’s much better than forcing everyone to have that database regardless of whether they need it or not…

Comment: You can download the latest Apache Derby software from http://db.apache.org/derby